# Prevent refetch api on route query param change

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, vue.js, vue-router

this is my page script:

```
created() {
    this.fetchCategories();
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions(['fetchCategories']),
  },
```

as you see when page loads it fetch API automatically.

and here I open modals based on route query changes:

```
 watch: {
    // open dialog on route query
    loading({ status, type }) {
      if (type === 'index' && !status) {
        const formQuery = this.$route.query.form;

        if (formQuery) {
          if (formQuery === 'create') {
            [this.dialog, this.formType] = [true, 0];
          } else if (formQuery === 'edit' && this.$route.query.id) {
            [this.dialog, this.formType] = [true, 1];
          } else if (formQuery === 'delete' && this.$route.query.id) {
            this.dialogDelete = true;
          }
        }
      }
    },
  },
```

and with these methods I push router with query param:

```
    openFormDialog(id = null) {
      this.dialog = true;

      if (id) {
        this.formType = 1;
        this.$router.push({ name: 'CategoryIndex', query: { form: 'edit', id } });
      } else {
        this.formType = 0;
        this.$router.push({ name: 'CategoryIndex', query: { form: 'create' } });
      }
    },
    openDeleteDialog(id) {
      this.$router.push({ name: 'CategoryIndex', query: { form: 'delete', id } });
      this.dialogDelete = true;
    },
  },
```

this method close modal and push router (remove query params):

```
 close() {
      this.$emit('input', false);
      this.$router.push({ name: 'CategoryIndex' });
    },
```

problem is that when I remove (or redirect back to 'CategoryIndex' page), page component will rerendered and it fetch API again. how can I fix that? what is the solution?

Comment: You can define a getter and check the store for fetchCategories, if its has some data, dont call the API, else call the API as usual

Comment: @NishantPatel when i create a new category i should fetch api again!

Comment: Then read from the this.$route.params, on what kind of query is it. If its `query.form === 'delete'`, you can add a condition that `created() { if (query.form !== 'delete'){
    this.fetchCategories();}
  },`

Comment: @NishantPatel at first load it should fetch api, and if delete or create or ... happen it should fetch it again

Comment: Then why dont you move `this.fetchCategories();` from created() to your watcher